# I deleted a git branch by mistake, how can I recover it?

Tags: git, gitlab

I pushed my branch to the gitlab and then deleted my local branch
but someone deleted remote branch by mistake
is there any way to recover my branch

Comment: You can use [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to find out the past locations of your branch then re-create it on its last position.

Answer (score 7):

1. If you just deleted the branch, you'll see something like this in your

```
Deleted branch <your-branch> (was <sha>)
```

To restore the branch, use:

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

2. If you don't know the 'sha' off the top of your head, you can:

Find the 'sha' for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch using:

```
git reflog
```

To restore the branch, use:

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

3. If your commits are not in your reflog:

You can try recovering a branch by reseting your branch to the sha of the commit found using a command like:

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt
```

You can then display each commit using one of these:

```
git log -p <commit>
git cat-file -p <commit>
```